# Unable to generate Crystal report- Incorrect Log on parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I have been trying to generate my report but this error keeps showing up. Can any one please tell me what can be the issue, what can be the possible solutions to rectify the problem.

```
Logon failed. Details: mscorlib : Could not find a part of the
path 'E:\OPCollectionSUMMARYReportXML.xml'. Error in File
C:\Users\arifkhan\AppData\Local\Temp\OPCollectionDetailsReport {89FDC9CF-5AE2-45E7-
B382- 28318AD342A2}.rpt: Unable to connect: incorrect log on parameters.
```

Configuration: C# (VS2005), Crystal Report 8, SQL Server Management Studio.

Thanks in Advance and have a good day!

Comment: The error itself is self explanatory. Can you make sure that the Path 'E:\OPCollectionSUMMARYReportXML.xml' is correct and exists. Also in the report you are using or referring to that path that you have not mispelled it.

Comment: Yes sir, I checked to make sure the path was correct. I dont think that's the issue. It still displays the same error.

Comment: Do you have any subreports in your report?
Just out of curiosity as you mentioned Sql Server management studio: does your report access any database?

Comment: Can you debug this? If you can, you can see whats happening at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

We solved 4 issues like that this week, i will share here.

1. A report with a subreport. The main report and the subreport use the same XSD as the data source. The XSD defines 5 tables. The 5 tables was added to the main report, but only 3 was added to the subreport. We removed the 2 "extra" tables of the main report and it worked.
2. We had another issue very similar to the first one, but the main report had fewer tables. We just added the "extra" tables in the main report, so that the main report and the subreport now have the same tables and it worked.
3. A coworker said he put "content" as the "build action" of the XSD file in the visual studio project and it supposedly worked. But i did not tried it to check.
4. A report was using 2 XSD files. We changed it to use only 1 XSD files and it worked.