# Failed logon to database - Crystal Reports VS2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, crystal-reports

I had a project using `.NET framework 3.5(Visual Studio 2008)`, I migrated It to `Visual Studio 2015` and needed to install a new `Crystal reports SP`, which I did, and it's all working when I run it on `VS 2015`, but once I deploy it to `IIS 10` on our `AWS windows server`, everytime I try to generate a report I get

> "Failed logon to database"

I don't connect Crystal Reports directly to the Database, I just give it a datasource with `SetDataSource`.

I already installed the crystal reports SP runtime at the server and it still doesn't work.

Can anybody help?
Thanks

Comment: Can you log the exception and check the inner exception and other details?

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30759533/published-reports-dont-work-database-logon-failed-error/30780269#30780269)